# Using sed within a makefile

Tags: shell, sed, make, cygwin

I want to modify the cygwin path to the windows path from within a makefile.
For that purpose, I am using

```
CURDIR := `pwd`
WINDIR := $(shell echo $(CURDIR) | sed -e "s/\/cygdrive\/\(.\)/\1:/" | sed -e 's/\//\\/g')
```

When I execute this makefile using gnumake, i am faced with this error:

```
sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 8: Unterminated `s' command
```

However, when i execute the following command on the cygwin shell directly, I get the desired output:

```
$: pwd | sed -e "s/\/cygdrive\/\(.\)/\1:/" | sed -e 's/\//\\/g'
```

The above command works perfectly and there is no complaint from the shell of any sort.
Why am I facing this issue and what could be a possible remedy?

Comment: I don't know cygwin, but you might try changing `shell echo...` to `shell set -x; echo...` so that you can see on stderr what command is being passed to the shell for execution. Add the output to your question.

Comment: It seems you are trying to convert Cygwin's Linux path format to Windows'. If that is the case, please look into [cygpath](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html) command with the `--windows` option.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Hai Vu. It worked and provided the result I was after. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

To explain the problem you're seeing, it's happening in the second `sed` command:

```
sed -e 's/\//\\/g'
```

`make` uses `\` as a special character that can be used to escape `%`, so `\\` is an escape sequence that translates to `\` (a single backslash.)

Other than two backslashes in a row or when followed by `%`, the backslash is preserved verbatim, so `\/` is kept as `\/` and won't cause any problems (that's why only this place caused trouble.)

So the `sed` command that actually gets executed is:

```
sed -e 's/\//\/g'
```

It's easier to see how this command is incomplete if you use a different delimiter, such as `#`:

```
sed -e 's#/#/g'
```

First off, the ending delimiter (in this case `#`) is missing. Furthermore, the replacement is getting a `/` and not a `\` as intended.

You can fix it by adding an extra backslash (or two will also work):

```
sed -e 's/\//\\\/g'
```

But this might look quite odd to someone reading that code, so I'd recommend adding a comment to explain what is going on.

Another good idea would be to double *every* backslash, to make it clear that `make` is using one level of them as escape sequences:

```
sed -e 's/\\//\\\\/g'
```

Ugh, still pretty awful... Using a delimiter other than `#` might help a little bit, but probably not that much:

```
sed -e 's#/#\\\\#g'
```

---

For the specific case you're using `sed` here, which is to convert a Cygwin path to a Windows path, you can actually use [`cygpath --windows`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html), as pointed out by @HaiVu in comments.